# Google translator works on some occasions and not on some occassions

Tags: python, google-translate, geopy, language-translation, nominatim

I am doing reverse geocoding using Nominatim in geopy . It returns city or town names in a different language than English sometimes . I am translating those city names to English Names using `googletrans`.
However , google translator does give the result on some occasions and sometimes throws an error for the same translation.

For example:
`{'town': 'મુન્દ્રા', 'county': 'Mundra Taluka', 'state_district': 'Kutch District', 'state': 'Gujarat', 'postcode': '370421', 'country': 'India', 'country_code': 'in'}`

This is the result I am getting from Nominatim . Using the following command I am doing the translation.
`town=translator.translate(address.get('town')).text`. This does this give `Mundra` as an answer sometimes and sometimes not . Mainly , as I have observed , if I am querying a second time it returns an error or if i am running many such queries in a loop , it returns an error

Error is : `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` .

I have seen stackoverflow links where they suggest some issue with the raw token.However, those solutions don't help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you specify which version of the API you are using and how you are authenticating? I tried to reproduce the same problem but it worked withou problems.

Comment: as i said it sometimes gives an error not always but very unpredictable

Comment: I previously asked some information like version of API and method of authentication. May you provide this information?

Comment: version in 3.0.0 and no auth simply => translator=Translator()

Comment: I tried to reproduce this behavior but I couldn't find the same problem. If you still facing the same problem and you think it should be addressed as a possible defect, I encourage you creating an issue on IssueTracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187144&template=1161182)